# How to send new line character in url?

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I'm using `Vuejs` for frontend and I have `blade template` displayed using `iframe`. I want to send data into blade such that Whatever i type inside text field it should be displayed on the `laravel blade template`.

```
<iframe :src="template" @load="onTemplateLoad()"></iframe>
```

and `template` is defined as

```
this.template = '/templates/email_templates/' + t.id + '?footer_message=' + this.footer_message;
```

If there is any new line character in `footer_message` it should be displayed. Now it is ignoring the new line. Is there any way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway friends I got it, before appending the value just replace all new line character with `'%0A'`.
In my code I added this `message.replace(/\n/g, '%0A');`. Which Works fine.